# Internet Explorer: AudioContext undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, html5-audio

I was about to create an application for audio recording using asp.net MVC-5, And I have created one, but its having problem with IE. The application is using below JS code for creating AudioContext Object. But it is undefined in IE and hence throwing exception. Tried in IE10 and 11, both had same issue. But its working in Chrome. Could you please some one help me to overcome this ?

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();

Comment: As per MDN docs, `AudioContext` is not supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext

Comment: Is there any other alternative way that I can use to record microphone using html5 and JS ??